# Where to post code to be checked

Tags: python

I apologise if this is an obvious question.  I would like to know where to post code to be error-checked in the future, as am teaching myself Python and am hitting stumbling blocks in my code constantly.  It is usually blindingly obvious, as with the first dictionary error; for which I apologise.

*original dictionary error sorted*
*Missed out quote marks on 2nd line of code*

I am making a dictionary variable, but there appears to be a problem with it.

```
charAttr = {'Power':'5','Health':'5','Wisdom':'5','Dexterity':'5'}
basePow=int(charAttr[Power])
```

I am then given "NameError: name 'Power' is not defined."

Comment: Why are you using double single quotes `''` instead of a double quote `"`?

Comment: For one thing, double quotes is a single character `"` and not `''`

Comment: Change this: `basePow=int(charAttr[Power])` to this `basePow=int(charAttr['Power'])`

Comment: There is a code review StackExchange site: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [Online Peer Code Review?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542/online-peer-code-review)

Answer (score 4):

Either use single quotes (`'Power'`) or double quotes (`"Wisdom"`) to make a string literal. Double quotes are not the same as two single quotes.

---

As to your more general question: StackOverflow is indeed  a place for such things, but in general, you should provide more information with your question. The code you posted creates an error message: so you should post that error message. There's lots of information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on what makes a good question; I definitely recommend you read up on it.

Answer (score 0):

Two single quote != one double quote.

So not

```
''
```

but:

```
"
```

or you can use single quote as... single quote :P

Correct form is:

```
charAttr = {'Power':'5','Health':'5','Wisdom':'5','Dexterity':'5'}
```

or

```
charAttr = {"Power":"5","Health":"5","Wisdom":"5","Dexterity":"5"}
```